# Accessing first row in an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% question = @questions.try(:first) %>
<h1><%= question.title %></h1>
```

I'm trying to use the above code to grab the first question from a Questions model, and then display it's title in HTML.  However, I'm throwing the error `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`

Autogenerated RoR files use the `question.title` line... why isn't it working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`question.title` raises error as `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass` that means `question` is set as `nil`. You set `question` using

```
<% question = @questions.try(:first) %>
```

It means either `@questions` is nil or there `@questions.first` returns `nil`.

Make sure that you set `@questions` instance variable in the Controller's action which renders this particular view.

```
 def action_name
   @questions = Question.all
 end
```

Also, if you just want to show **only** the first `question` record in your view and you are not going to use `@questions` anywhere then just set

```
 def action_name
   @question = Question.first
 end
```

and use it in the view directly as:

```
<h1><%= @question.try(:title) %></h1>
```

Comment: Ahhh.. thank you!  I didn't have `@questions = Question.all` in my controller!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when timeout is over :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @question is nil. Have you assigned @question in your controller action. Can you show your code in your controller action?